# How to find reference resource implementation in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources, android-theme, android-styles

I mean, is it possible now to see platform's(exact sdk) implementation of reference attr?

[image]

This time I'm using Android Studio v2.3 and 3.0

Answer (score 1):

`selectableItemBackground` is an attribute, that is specified in themes.

For a reference you can see how topmost `Theme` style specifies that attribute, which is declared in [`themes.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml#132).

```
<style name="Theme">
    ...
    <item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/item_background</item>
    <item name="selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    ...
</style>
```

As to the question: *"How to find reference resource implementation in Android studio?"* - what you can do, is perform a search inside Android Studio with query "theme_material". That file, as the name applies, contains material themes, alternatively you can search for "themes" for non-material themes.

[image]

Also, you can make use of Android Studio's "Find in Path" feature:

[image]

In above screenshot you can see that I've specified search directory to point to SDK sources (in my case it's *"/Users/azizbekian/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27"*) and search query **"selectableitembackground">**